# Phpunit, mock / modify a method parameter itself

Tags: php, unit-testing

```
Class Testme
{
    public function testMe ($input, &$output)
    {
        $output = 9;
    }
}
```

as you all can see, this method modifies an input parameter. Now how to mock it? Something like mocking the return value

```
$mock = $this->getMock ('Testme');
$mock = $this->expects ($this->once())->with (1, 0)->will
```

what to write here to modify the 2nd parameter? I want the 2nd parameter to be 10.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $mock = $this->getMock('Testme');
 $mock->expects($this->once())
     ->method('testMe')
     ->with(1, 0)
     ->will(
         $this->returnCallback(
             function ($input, &$output) {
                 $output = 10;
             }
         )
     );
```

but beware! it still wouldn't work, cause of twice calling (issue: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects/issues/181)

you can work around this with this solution: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects/issues/181#issuecomment-52289669

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is not possible if you use PHPUnit Mock Objects. [See known issue #81 "Arguments that are passed by reference are not handled properly](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects/issues/81).

I would recommend to use [Prophecy](https://github.com/phpspec/prophecy) instead. Prophecy will be supported by default in PHPUnit >= 4.5. In the meanwhile you can include phpspec/prophecy-phpunit, which integrates prophecy in PHPUnit.

Here is a use case with Prophecy:

```
namespace SchlimmerFinger;

use Prophecy\PhpUnit\ProphecyTestCase;

class MockWithReferenceTest extends ProphecyTestCase
{
    public function testShouldChangeValue()
    {
        $foo = $this->prophesize(__NAMESPACE__ . '\\Foo');

        $a = 20;
        $b = 35;
        $c = 22;

        $foo->bar($a, $b, $c)->will(function(array $arguments) use (&$b){
            $arguments[1] = $b = 10;
            return array_sum($arguments);
        });

        self::assertEquals(52, $foo->reveal()->bar($a, $b, $c));
        self::assertEquals(10, $b);
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public function bar($a, &$b, $c)
    {
    }
}
```